# My boolean value does not change in database Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i need help.. My boolean value not changes in database.. Im using laravel 8

Here's my code in PostController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'post_title' => 'required|string|max:60',
        'post_slug' => 'required|string|unique:posts,post_slug',
        'post_thumbnail' => 'required',
        'post_excerpt' => 'required|string|max:500',
        'post_seq' => 'required',
        'post_description' => 'required|string',
        'post_meta_title' => 'required|string|max:60',
        'post_meta_description' => 'required|string|max:250',
        'post_meta_keyword' => 'required|string',
        'is_active' => 'required'
    ]);

    Post::create([
        'post_title' => $request->post_title,
        'post_slug' => $request->post_slug,
        'post_seq' => $request->post_seq,
        'post_thumbnail' => parse_url($request->post_thumbnail)['path'],
        'post_excerpt' => $request->post_excerpt,
        'post_description' => $request->post_description,
        'post_meta_title' => $request->post_meta_title,
        'post_meta_description' => $request->post_meta_description,
        'post_meta_keyword' => $request->post_meta_keyword,
        'is_active' => $request->has('is_active'),
        'user_id' => $request->user_id
    ]);
    Alert::success('Add Post', 'Added Post Success');
    // dd($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}
```

and here's my code in create.blade.php

```
<!-- status -->
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('is_active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="is_active" id="is_active">
             <option value="1" @if (old('is_active')==1) selected @endif>True</option>
             <option value="0" @if (old('is_active')==0) selected @endif>False</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

When i did dd($request->all()); it show correct, the is_active field change as i choose, true = 1 false = 0

But in my database, is_active boolean value is still 0.. Please help

Comment: did you added `is_active` on `fillable` ?

Comment: In my case the **interger** not worked, but the **string** works fine , you can try`'is_active' => ($request->is_active) ? '1' : '0');`

Comment: Yes i did 
protected $fillable = ['post_title', 'post_slug', 'post_thumbnail', 'post_seq', 'post_excerpt', 'post_description', 'post_meta_title', 'post_meta_description', 'post_meta_keyword', 'is-active'];

Comment: Where should i put this?
'is_active' => ($request->is_active) ? '1' : '0');

Comment: change this line `'is_active' => $request->has('is_active'),` to `'is_active' => ($request->is_active) ? '1' : '0'),`

Comment: Show this: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'
Don't know what i have to fix
Sorry, i'm a newbie..

Comment: opps, my bad, it would be `'is_active' => ($request->is_active) ? '1' : '0',`

Comment: it did change in when i dd($request->all()); But still not change in database

Comment: You can also use `'is_active' => $request->boolean('is_active')` to cast whatever is there to a boolean

Comment: is my create.blade.php correct?

Comment: It is not working.. i dont know why, in dd it show what we choose, but in mysql still 0